# Undefined symbols for architecture armv6 in Jailbreak Tweak

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I followed this tutorial and the source code : http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/

And then, I downloaded the "Sample Code : CryptTest" from the tutorial, it works perfectly in my Xcode 4.2. (With iOS SDK 4.2)

But when I want to add these source code to my iOS jailbreak tweak, the terminal always shows this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Base64", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Tweak.xm.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
```

This is my source code, can anyone check whether I made some mistakes?
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/809728/base64.zip

(In my source code, I make AES encrypt start to work when a "q" key of QWERTY keyboard shows in iPhone)

Comment: If your interested in this question why not support the Area 51 proposal for a [jail-breaking Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=EuWVi6IpN0_KzzEhC7I-Qw2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .zip seemed to be missing some files. I can't even get it to compile with Theos ("decode" method in NSData was missing). Anyway, I looked at your code. To get Class object, use the following in your Tweak.xm and it should link properly.

```
Class Base64 = objc_getClass("Base64");
```

Comment: For other getting this error and using logos (theos), you can just use `%c(Base64)` instead.